# service bus receive not returning immediately

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure Service Bus Topic/Subscriptions and running into unexplained performance with receiving messages.

According to MSDN:

> If Zero is passed in serverWaitTime, then there will be no wait time.
>   Instead server bus will fetch whatever messages are immediately
>   available, or return null as a result.

In my code, which is stripped down to bare essentials, I pass in a 0, but then the receive takes 60 seconds to complete.  When it completes, I get passed back a null object.  Why does it take 60 seconds when it should return immediately?

```
var client = ServiceBusClient.GetOrCreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName, false);

var msg = client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
```